# Node js. How to understand s1 = s2 === s3 and s1 && s2?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to fix code, but I stopped at two rows of code that are so weird I can't understand them. All rows:

```
//Extraction of urls
let f = !this.last_product_url
for(const productLink of productLinks) {
    const url = await productLink.getAttribute('href')

    if(!f) {
        f = url === this.last_product_url
        f && productUrls.push(url)
    }
    else {
        productUrls.push(url)
    }
}
```

What are these two rows do:

```
f = url === this.last_product_url
f && productUrls.push(url)
```

Comment: Could you clarify which part is unclear - assignment? Strict equality comparison? Logical operator?

Comment: This is two questions in one. The first line has a strict equality comparison, and the second line has the `&&` logical operator.

Comment: I don't understand both. Why we strict compare after assignment? And what will logical operator change?

Comment: Editorial remark.  Too clever is dumb. If the person maintaining your code has to ask SO what your syntax means, you were too clever. Parentheses were made for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntactically, this is what happens:

`f = url === this.last_product_url`:

Check for strict equality between variables `url` and `this.last_product_url` and assign to `f`.

---

`f && productUrls.push(url)`:

If `f` is `true`, push `url` to `productUrls`.

This works as follows. The statement `A && B` is evaluated, but `B` is only checked if `A` is true, since if `A` is false, `A && B` is never true. Thus, if `A` is true, then `B` is checked: the url is pushed.

Comment: @Midriaz no problem!

Answer (score 2):

`f = url === this.last_product_url` will assign the result of `url === this.last_product_url` to f.

f && productUrls.push(url) is same as below:

```
if(f) productUrls.push(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

The two lines are doing

```
f = (url === this.last_product_url);
if (f) {
  productUrls.push(url);
}
```

The loop body could be clarified by writing

```
let f = !this.last_product_url;
for (const productLink of productLinks) {
    const url = await productLink.getAttribute('href')

    if (!f) {
        f = (url === this.last_product_url);
    }
    if (f) {
        productUrls.push(url);
    }
}
```

But what this weird `f` flag really does is to take all urls from `productLinks` after the one where `url === this.last_product_url`. So the whole thing should probably be written as

```
const allProductUrls = await Promise.all(productLinks.map(productLink =>
    productlink.getAttribute('href');
));
const lastIndex = this.last_product_url 
  ? allProductUrls.indexOf(this.last_product_url)
  : 0;
if (lastIndex > -1) {
    productUrls.push(...allProductUrls.slice(lastIndex));
}
```

Comment: What about just `if(f || url === this.last_product_url)`?

Comment: @A.J.Uppal That doesn't work as `f` is used in the successive iterations as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
f = url === this.last_product_url
f && productUrls.push(url)
```

These two lines of code are compact way of representing below logic:

```
if(url === this.last_product_url){
      productUrls.push(url);
}
```

Comment: How to make a simple `if` hard to read... :/ The second block of code is way easier to understand

Answer (score 1):

`f = url === this.last_product_url` is equivalent to

```
if (url === this.last_product_url) {
 f = true;
} else {
 f = false;
}
```

And

`f && productUrls.push(url)` is equivalent to

```
if (f) {
 productUrls.push(url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

f = url === this.last_product_url  -> f = (url === this.last_product_url) -> returns boolean value based on url and this.last_product_url comparison

f && productUrls.push(url) -> push function will be called only when f is true -> if(f) { productUrls.push(url) }